# How can I show figures independent of screen resolution in python tkinter with matplotlib?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run this code of python to plot on a Ultra HD screen, the **icons and texts on figure seem too small** (if you can see at all).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 500, endpoint=False)
plt.plot(t, scipy.signal.square(2 * np.pi * 5 * t))
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.show()
```

Here is how it is seen:
[image]

I would like my app independent of screen resolution, ie, the icons, texts, etc. are shown as some acceptable size (equal percentage of screen on all resolutions, for example).

How could I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution in dots per inch of a saved figure can be be controlled with the the dpi argument to [savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig). Maybe it helps with less resolution monitors

```
savefig(fname, dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
        orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
        transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
        frameon=None)
```

The argument def:

```
dpi: [ None | scalar > 0 | ‘figure’]
```

The resolution in dots per inch. If None it will default to the value savefig.dpi in the matplotlibrc file. If ‘figure’ it will set the dpi to be the value of the figure.

Comment: Hello. I'm not interested in saving figure.